# How can I apply Javascript properly?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, there are four containers, each containing an image, I added a script that provides the ability to view the full image. But this function only works for the first container.

```
const img = document.querySelector("img");
const icons = document.querySelector(".icons");
img.onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    icons.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

Html:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/3007/3007960.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="title">
            Jeffrey
        </div>
        <div class="place">
            Age | City, Country</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                User Interface Designer and <br>front-end developer</p>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button>Message</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button>Following</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icons">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="fab fa-facebook-f"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="fab fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="fab fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated HTML (1), some details; I changed the names for each container and wrapper, created different CSS files for each new one and it did not work, here is a part of the new updated html:

```
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="wrapper3">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/3007/3007960.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="title">
  Name</div>
<div class="place">
  Age | City, Country</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
        <p>
User Interface Designer and <br>front-end developer</p>
<div class="buttons">
          <div class="btn">
            <button>Message</button>
          </div>
<div class="btn">
            <button>Following</button>
          </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="icons">
<li><a href="#"><span class="fab fa-facebook-f"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="fab fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="fab fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
</div>
</div>
<script>
      const images = [...document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper img, .wrapper1 img, .wrapper2 img, .wrapper3 img")];

images.forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener("click", function() {
    images
      .filter(img => img !== this)
      .forEach(img => img.classList.remove("active"));

    this.classList.toggle("active");
    </script>
```

Comment: `.querySelector()` returns the first matched element. Use `.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Try using querySelectorAll

Comment: Doesnt work yet.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Comment: No, but I tried inserting the script after each <div class="container">, and it didn't work too.

Comment: Sean, check the post again please.

Answer (score 1):

You need querySelectorAll and a for loop.
Try:

```
const img = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
img[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
     console.log(e);
});
}
```

Comment: The `NodeList` from `.querySelectorAll()` offers a `.forEach()` method

Comment: This means the owner of the Object. In this case, this targets the img which you click on it.

Answer (score 1):

**Modify this to your liking. Have fun...**

```js
const images = [...document.querySelectorAll(".images-2 img, .images img")];

images.forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener("click", function() {
    images
      .filter(img => img !== this)
      .forEach(img => img.classList.remove("active"));

    this.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.images,
.images-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.images-2 img,
.images img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.images-2 img.active,
.images img.active {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px -10px #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature?1" />
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature?2" />
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature?3" />
</div>

<div class="images-2">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature?4" />
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature?5" />
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature?6" />
</div>
```

Comment: The `NodeList` from `.querySelectorAll()` offers a `.forEach()` method

Comment: True. but `filter` method is required as well.

Comment: I created 4 differently named containers and wrappers, I created extra CSS files for the different wrappers and containers, applied the script with this start:       const images = [...document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper img, .wrapper1 img, .wrapper2 img, .wrapper3 img")];

Comment: please update your question (source code). so i can have clear view what went wrong.

Comment: Check the post.

Comment: does this resolve your issue. [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/mw5dzunt/1/)

Comment: No, I think I'll just remove it.